# CSS Background and Text Align

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a CSS backgroun using a picture, but I am failing somewhere. The problem is that when I put a lot of content on the page, the picture gets bigger and the quality goes down. I tried to fix it with Position:fixed but not working. Here's the code:

```
html{
background:url(BACKGROUND.jpg) no-repeat center center;
min-height:100%;
background-size:cover;
}
```

Also i tried to put a text-align:justify in the code but didn't work out too. I am messing something up really bad. Would love to get some help!

Comment: We could help you better if  you posted more of the relevant code (html AND css)

Comment: If I understand you correct, you're adding a background image (full-width body / or container ?) and are surprised that if the container gets bigger your image is starts to look low-pixeled. 

Solution 1: Just use a high-res image (e.g. 1920x1080 px) and it will look fine at most resolutions, but (!) this will result in a long network load as your iamge size will get bigger.

Comment: It's loading on the full screen , but the problem is when I start putting information in the BODY and the pictures gets resized and that demage the quality.

Comment: you really should link to a page or jsfiddle sth. Before that it is more like a "needle in a haystack" search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cover make :](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover)

> Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area

You should use `contain` instead

Comment: It's not helping. It's loading on the full screen as before, but the problem is when I start putting information in the BODY and the pictures gets resized and that demage the quality.

Comment: @DanielaGocheva try with `initial` then

Comment: @DanielaGocheva then I'll need more code, I can't just guess the answer :)

Comment: just fixed it! It seems all I had to do is add fixed in the end of background:url(BACKGROUND.jpg) no-repeat center center;

Answer (score 0):

Try the

```
background-size: contain;
```

Because "cover" means "make it cover the entire box.

Comment: It's not helping. It's loading on the full screen as before, but the problem is when I start putting information in the BODY and the pictures gets resized and that demage the quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can vary background-size like 50% or 60%

```css
html{
background:url(BACKGROUND.jpg) no-repeat center center;
min-height:100%;
background-size:50% 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
background:url(BACKGROUND.jpg) no-repeat center center;
min-height:600px;/*use images height*/
height:auto;
width:1000px;
background-size:100% 40%;
```